# Implement last using ML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

I'm trying to implement last in ML. last can return the last element of a list.

For example, L=[1, 2, 3, 4], last(L) = 4. Here is my implementation.

```
fun last [] = last((h::nil)) = h | last((h::tail)) = last(tail);
```

It give me "unbound variable or constructor: h". In my understanding, h is a variable declared by me, representing the head of the list, why error would occur on variable h?

Comment: "I didn't work" is not a helpful specification of errant behavior that can be used to help you. *What* didn't work? *How* didn't it work? Did you get an error message? If yes, what was the *exact* error message? Did you get a warning message? If yes, what was the *exact* warning message? Did you not get the expected result? If yes, which result did you get, which result did you expect, why did you expect that result, and in what way does the actual result differ from the expected result? Did you not observe the expected behavior? If yes, which behavior did you observe, which behavior did you …

Comment: … expect, why did you expect that behavior, and in what way does the actual behavior differ from the expected behavior? Please, give a precise specification of the expected behaviors and results, including any and all possible exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases. Please, provide examples of inputs and desired outputs and behaviors, demonstrating both normal cases as well as possible exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases. What did you try to debug the problem? How did you try to isolate it? What steps did you perform to narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definition can be laid out as

```
fun last [] = last((h::nil)) = h 
| last((h::tail)) = last(tail);
```

SML interprets the first clause as an attempt to assign to `last []` the Boolean value which is the result of the comparison `last((h::nil)) = h`. Since the pattern that you are matching in that clause is `[]` and `[]` doesn't involve `h`, the `h` in the comparison `last((h::nil)) = h` is unbound, hence the error. In any event such a comparison would make very little sense and is clearly not your intention.

Note that `last []` can't be sensibly defined. You alternatives is to either simply ignore it or to address it by raising an error (either `Empty` or a custom error). The real basis clause of the function `last` is that of a 1-element list. You seem to know how to handle it. Your code actually works when you stop trying to use your first clause to simultaneously give a value to both `last []` and `last (h::nil)` and instead just do the latter:

```
fun last (h::nil) = h 
| last (h::tail) = last tail;
```

Here I removed 3 pairs of superfluous parentheses around `h::nil`, `h::tail`, and `tail`. In SML function invocation requires no parentheses. You only need parentheses when you need to insure proper grouping. Note that the first pattern can also be written more succintly as `[h]`.

You get a nonexahaustive match warning since you haven't given a definition for `last []`. You could just ignore the warning (since it is rather common with functions only defined for nonempty lists), or write it as

```
fun last [] = raise Empty
|   last (h::nil) = h 
|   last (h::tail) = last tail;
```